# How to set the hostname for docker container when using Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a Gitlab CI pipeline using docker image. For some reason, I need to set the host name of the docker container to a special value.

When running docker container locally, this can be done by specifying the -h|--hostname option. But in gitlab's official help document, it seems that only 'name' and 'entrypoint' keywords are supported for setting 'image' in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Is there anyway to set the docker container's host name?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found one solution from this page by myself: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section

Here are my steps:

1. Run 'gitlab-runner register' to register a runner and select docker
   as executor.
2. Open /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml file.
3. Insert 'hostname = "xxxx"' into the '[runners.docker]' section of
   the registered runner.

To restrict the docker containers that will use the hostname set in step 3, you can:

- Insert 'allowed_images = ["xxx:xxx"]' into the '[runners.docker]' section of the registered runner.
- Set some tag for the runner and specify the 'tags' together with 'image' in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: I tried running `gitlab-runner register`under the `before_script:` section of in my gitlab-ci.yml file, but got "command not found", so I assume this is not how you use this. Do you know of a way to change the hostname of the docker container once it's running?

Comment: @JoeTidee I run `gitlab-runner register` under my test OS with docker-ce installed, and just specify docker image in gitlab-ci.yml. The container will be created and destroyed by gitlab during a pipeline. It seems you are trying to register a new runner in a job which is executing by an existing runner, and there's no `gitlab-runner` under the runner environment. For changing hostname of a container, you can try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/716719/how-do-i-change-docker-host-name-after-the-image-creation